# Is there a general command to see what shell is running?

Tags: shell

On some the shell can be read on in the command prompt, other can be seen when `help` is ran. But this are not covered by all the shells.

Is there a general command to see what shell is running?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are right default is ambiguos I edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work with most shells and most OSes:

```
$ ps -o comm -p $$ | tail -n -1
ksh93
```

Edit: after reading the duplicate link, here is a simpler way that avoids the tail command.

```
$ ps -o comm= -p $$
ksh93
```

Comment: @jillagre Strange, the standard allows (and mentions) both syntaxes. So `-n -1` and `-n 1` are equivalent, while `-n +1` is not. Bizarre.

Comment: I guess that's for historical reasons. Pre-standard tail didn't implemented the -n option, that was `tail -1` for the last line and `tail +1` for the first one. They kept the same syntax when `-n` was added not to break habits/usage. Not specifying a sign shouldn't but mean the last line(s), as the `-` in `tail -1` was more to introduce an option than a sign indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in /etc/passwd file, or type:

```
echo $SHELL
```

or

```
env
```

to see your default shell.

Comment: Looking in /etc/passwd assumes that the user account exists in /etc/passwd, which may not be the case (for example in the case of such information being stored in LDAP, AD or other remote repositories).